# Persistence provider not found

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

everyone. I'm new to JPA 2.0. I'm using maven and eclipse, as well as eclipse link. I have this in my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="certifications">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.entities.NicdsCliCertificationStg</class>
        <class>com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.entities.NicdsCliCertificationStgPK</class>
        <class>com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.entities.NicdsCliUpMapping</class> 
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>          
        <properties>            
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:5455:orcl"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="ni"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="NI"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
        </properties>       
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And I have this code in a facade to get the entity manager.

```
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

protected EntityManager getEntityManager(){
    if(emf == null){
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("certifications");
    }
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

When I get to this part, it always returns "No persistence provider for EntityManager named certifications". I made sure that the persistence.xml is in the META-INF and the META-INF is part of the classpath. Any ideas? Thanks!!

--EDIT--
Stacktrace added

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.exception.CertificationException: Internal Server Error
    at com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.controller.AbstractFacade.getContactIdByUpId(AbstractFacade.java:28)
    at com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.controller.CertificationFacade.getCertificationsByUpId(CertificationFacade.java:14)
    at com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.dao.CertificationDAO.getCertificationByUpId(CertificationDAO.java:13)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named certifications
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.controller.AbstractFacade.getEntityManager(AbstractFacade.java:17)
    at com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.controller.AbstractFacade.getContactIdByUpId(AbstractFacade.java:25)
```

Comment: can you please post stacktrace

Comment: do you have org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jar also in your classpath?

Comment: Since I use maven, I believe it's added automatically to the classpath. I'm checking the imports, and it says that it added javax.persistence_2.0.0.v01002051058.jar. Is it the same?

Comment: Ok, I checked the eclipselink wiki (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven) and it says that adding to maven the eclipselink dependency should add all eclipselink artifacts, including org.eclipse.persistence.jpa

Comment: What artifacts are you pulling and ohow have you configured it?  You need  org.eclipse.persistence.jpa and org.eclipse.persistence.core.  javax.persistence_2.0.0.v01002051058.jar contains only the java.persistence JPA interface classes.

Comment: You need eclipselink.2.x.x.jar

Comment: I dont have eclipseLink, but openjpa and the path to persistence.xml is configured in pom in plugin section, maybe it will help you or you can post your pom configuration, if you have